# How can I make <footer> stick to the bottom of the screen when content is short, and to the bottom of content when content is long?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a footer tag (after a body tag inside main tag):

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d9efef;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <main>
      short html content
    </main>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <p>
      Some Text (large amount)
    </p>
  </footer>
```

On a desktop it's relatively nicely styled (even though it's fixed and not after content).
On mobile though, it becomes very tall and is annoying to constantly have on the bottom of the screen.

How can I make the footer stay below the content at all times, but also stay at the bottom of the screen when the page content is short?

(The stackoverflow.com footer is kind of what I'm thinking about)

Comment: Am I missing something here? Both desktop and mobile looks fine with context with scrollbars and without.

Comment: @vanowm the original site footer has a lot more content in it, as do some of the sites pages, on mobile this is very uncomfortable, as the footer (being fixed) is constantly on screen. I couldn't copy full structure because It's a dynamic web application. go here to see actual structure: https://ide-b87400ce60984c7983e31e7cbafae21f-8080.cs50.ws/

Comment: Perhaps add more information about "desktop" (browser(s), including version(s) and operating system (including version) and "mobile" (operating system (including version)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` for this.

For the following markup

```html
<body>
  <main>main content here</main>
  <footer>footer here</footer>
</body>
```

The CSS would be:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0;
}
footer {
  flex: 0 0;
}
```

What it does is make the body at least span the entire height and it's children layout following the 'flex' system.  With a flexbox you can then specify for each child how it should behave.

The `flex: 1 0;` in the main will tell the browser to have main take as much place as possible and grow to do so. While `flex: 0 0;` in the footer tells the browser to not grow the footer.

Comment: no, that can be removed, I also forgot to mention html also needs a 100% style (updated the answer)

Comment: it will not work when you have either little content or a smaller screen. I checked the site you linked in one of the comments and the footer is not at the bottom, but floating around the middle

Comment: Yeah just noticed it myself, I was looking at mobile, not at desktop mode.